# Setting a configuration parameter for functions implemented in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've written a couple of functions in PL/pgSQL and I would like to control their behavior through some configuration entries, changeable at run time too (per session). Is it possible to define new custom-defined configuration entries in `postgresql.conf`? If not, what's the work around?

As my search results, I came across the [part of documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-custom.html) which says:

> **18.16. Customized Options**
>
> This feature was designed to allow parameters not normally known to
>   PostgreSQL to be added by add-on modules (such as procedural
>   languages). This allows extension modules to be configured in the
>   standard ways.

If this passage answers my question with a "No", can my PL/pgSQL functions be considered an **extension module** so that they can have their own configuration entries in the configuration file?

Comment: Any kind, but for now a boolean will do

Comment: Perhaps there's been a misunderstanding, the configuration I'm looking for is absolutely tailored to my needs and has nothing to do with the PostgreSQL or PL/pgSQL behavior. It's something I would like to check in my code to enable / disable a part of code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `subsequent calls`, but what I'm looking for is whether some part of the code is active or not. Consider an `if` statement checking whether some part of the code should be executed or not. It's as simple as that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define your custom parameters in `postgresql.conf`. Just append a line (e.g.):

```
my_param.new_param = 'something'
```

and reload configuration (or restart server).

In your client you can access the parameter with `show` command:

```
SHOW my_param.new_param;
```

or with `current_setting()` function:

```
SELECT current_setting('my_param.new_param');
```

You can change the current parameter (locally in the session):

```
SET my_param.new_param TO 'new value';
```

It is also possible to define custom parameters for a database:

```
ALTER DATABASE test SET my_param.new_param TO 'new test value';
-- each new client to the database will see the parameter with new value
-- current setting of the parameter remains unchanged

-- or
SET my_param.new_param TO 'new test value';
ALTER DATABASE test SET my_param.new_param FROM CURRENT;
```

A custom parameter must contain a period. Formally, the prefix should indicate the extension to which it relates, but Postgres does not check it in any way. You can have many custom parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I went as far as setting my custom entry but then I only tried `pg_settings` and could not find my entry there so I thought there should be a module defining the entry before I can use it.

Comment: can It be removed?

Comment: @DIEGOF.G. - You cannot remove a local custom parameter (set in a current session). For a database - use `alter database test reset my_param.new_param;` (the effect will be visible in next sessions, not in the current one)