# How to transform a file into INSERT with foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Coming from my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485316/postgresql-a-valid-variable-assignation-sample), the answers were valid but I tried to transform MySQL to PostgreSQL. This is not the best way to do what I need.

I have a file with more than 600 000 objects:

```
paper
pen
whatever
...
```

All those objects are listed in a "cyclic" colors, and *I know what the cycle look like but it's not in the file itself*, so, to give you an example (it's much longer than the example, but I hope you get the idea):

```
- black + red
- black + blue
- black + yellow
- white + red
- white + blue
- white + yellow
- black + red
- black + blue
- ....
```

I've separated those colors into a table wisely named "`colors`", and I've created another table named "`group_colors`", which is a many_to_many relationship with `colors`. The `objects` will have a one_to_one relationship with `group_colors`

I want to generate my own script, **and only one script** that:

- creates tables `colors`, `group_colors` and `objects`
- creates `INSERT` statements for `colors`
- based on those previous `INSERT` statements use the `ID`'s of `colors` to creates `INSERT` statements for `group_colors`
- from now on, creates `INSERT` statements for `objects`
- based on the `ID`'s of `group_colors` and `ID`'s of just inserted `object`, creates `INSERT` statements for `objects_group_colors`

This script should starts like that:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS color;
CREATE TABLE color (
   id AUTOINC,
   description VARCHAR(50)
)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS group_colors;
CREATE TABLE group_colors(
   id AUTOINC,
   description VARCHAR(50)
)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS group_colors_color;
CREATE TABLE group_colors_color(
   group_colors_id INT,
   color_id INT,
   group_colors_id INT,
   CONSTRAINT color_id NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES color(id),
   CONSTRAINT group_colors_id NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES group_colors(id)
)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS obj;
CREATE TABLE obj(
   id AUTOINC,
   description VARCHAR(50),
   group_colors_id INT,
   CONSTRAINT group_colors_id NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES group_colors(id)
)
```

And so on. The problem is not in creating table, it's in how to INSERT VALUES and re-use the `ID`'s of those values later on (very very late (>600 000 rows)), and *more than once*.

How would you do?

Comment: Design problem. Belongs on Programmers.SE.

Comment: What about scalar subqueries? Having already inserted the animal type of "cat" and the style of "nyan," you can retrieve those assigned IDs in-line to create the nyan cat character...  `INSERT INTO character (animal_type_id, style_id) VALUES ( (SELECT id FROM animal_type WHERE name = 'cat'), (SELECT id FROM style WHERE name = 'nyan') );`

Comment: A small but complete example of desired values in `color`, `group_color`, `objects_group_colors`, and `objects` tables will be helpful. Now it's unclear what a color cycle is, how it's related to color groups, and how color groups should be assigned to objects.

Comment: @EgorRogov question updated, I hope it's more clear now

Comment: I'm just asking for a working sample of a few lines in my questions

Comment: Still can't get it, sorry. How are you going to group the colors? How are you going to assign these groups to objects? (I think it's possible to solve the problem by generating appropriate ids, so that you can just calculate them and don't need to look up in the tables.)

Comment: i need to try, delete rows then try again, so i should not generate "hard coded" ids. that's my problem. I'm going to group the colors with the table "group_colors". a `group_colors` can have one or many `colors`. Those are 2 tables linked via a manytomany relationship. I'm sorry I dont know how to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to feed all that data as a big static file to the `psql` command line interpreter.

So you might want to use the `\gset` command to get back at the values inserted previously and load them into psql variables (see psql manpage), which can then be reinjected into other statements further in the script.

Example:

```
create table ref (id serial primary key, name text);
create table points_to_ref(fk int references ref(id));
insert into ref(name) values('foobar');
-- more queries here...
-- now get back at what we inserted first
select id as id_xyz from ref where name='foobar';
\gset
insert into points_to_ref values (:id_xyz);
```

The point of `\gset` is to create a psql variable from each column returned by the last SQL statement. Then you can reinject them with the `:varname` syntax. Make sure they're quoted properly, as explained in the doc. In the above example, `:id_xyz` contains a simple integer, so no quoting is necessary.

The server never sees these variables. It's a textual replacement that happens client-side. It's a quite different way than the accepted answer in the question you linked:
[PostgreSQL: a valid variable assignation sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485316/postgresql-a-valid-variable-assignation-sample)
It seems to me that it's closer to your MySQL script.

Also `\gset` is relatively new in psql (9.3 I think), make sure you don't use an older version.

Comment: You're right: that's *exaclty* what I was looking for in my previous question. Your answer is perfect for both questions. Up you! In between I started to make all that with a Python script and it's gone so far that I'll finish that first, then if it doesn't work i'll try your solution